# Popup on mouse enter and hide on mouseout

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-ajax

I was trying to apply a pop up control to a Link button on my ASP.NET website. The popup appears only on button click. How can the behavior be moedified to make the popup appear when on mouseover and ide on mouseout?

Button code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" CssClass="btn green"  ToolTip="NewProfile" Text="NewPlugin" 
           runat="server" Width="175px" onclick="AddBtn_Click" /><br /><br />
```

For popup control:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" CssClass="popupControl">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        Administrative previliges are required for this action.                            
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:Panel>             
       <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="LinkButton2" PopupControlID="Panel4" Position="Right">
       </asp:PopupControlExtender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a JQuery Function that does exactly the same thing you are trying to do...

```
$(".deal-hotel").live('mouseover',
function() {
    $(this).find('.deal-hotel-popup').show();
}).live('mouseout',
function() {
    $(this).find('.deal-hotel-popup').hide();
});
```

Yet changing the HTML Attribute for onclick to onmouseover should get you there. [Read This](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onmouseover)

On a side note switching to JQuery will make you like a lot easier.